# Access 2016 SQL: Find minimum absolute difference between two columns of different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to put together this SQL string. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out. I am using Access 2016, so please only provide answers that will work with Access. I have two queries that both have different fields except for one in common. I need to find the minimum absolute difference between the two similar columns. Then, I need to be able to pull the data from that corresponding record. For instance,

```
qry1.Col1  |  qry1.Col2
-----------|-----------
10245.123  | Have
302044.31  | A

qry2.Col1 | qry2.Col2
----------------------
23451.321 | Great
345622.34 | Day
```

Find minimum absolute difference in a third query, qry3. For instance, Min(Abs(qry1!Col1 - qry2!Col1) I imagine it would produce one of these tables for each value in qry1.Col1. For the value 10245.123,

```
qry3.Col1
----------
13206.198
335377.217
```

Since 13206.198 is the minimum absolute difference, I want to pull the record corresponding to that from qry2 and associate it with the data from qry1 (I'm assuming this uses a JOIN). Resulting in a fourth query like this,

```
qry4.Col1 (qry1.Col1) | qry4.Col2 (qry1.Col2) | qry4.Col3 (qry2.Col2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10245.123             | Have                  | Great
302044.31             | A                     | Day
```

If this is all doable in one SQL string, that would be great. If a couple of steps are required, that's okay as well. I just would like to avoid having to time consumingly do this using loops and RecordSet.Findfirst in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select q1.*,
       (select top 1 q2.col2
        from qry2 as q2
        order by abs(q2.col1 - q1.col1), q2.col2
       ) as qry2_col2
from qry1 as q1;
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to select multiple columns of data in the same record as the top 1?

Comment: Ah I see that I can just add additional select top subqueries for the additional fields. However, when I do so, Access is telling me "At most, one record can be selected from this subquery."

Comment: @Josh . . . MS Access really does `TOP WITH TIES`.  You can fix this by including a unique key as the last key in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: What would be the best way to combine data from two tables (technically one table and one query) where I have to match data from the table on 3 columns [userID, ACounter, and Min(Abs(time2-time1))] then select (or join) associated data from a table (say lat, long, alt) into one query row? Then on the same query record, do this again, but for a different userID. Essentially this is to compose a query of data that shows both a userID for a send and a userID for a receive with position info for both all in one record.